# Flag an answer after removing cursing?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

I have been flagging answers where I have removed cursing so that mods are aware of a user in the case they violate the rules on a regular basis.  Should I not flag it after I have removed the cursing?

Comment: The help link saying cursing is not allowed leads to a [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) where the top answer says it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether a flag is needed depends on whether you think the issue merits moderator attention.

The Stack Exchange system is designed so that many of the moderation tasks can be handled by a community of high-reputation users.  If it looks like editing the question solved the problem, then moderator intervention would be unnecessary.  On the other hand, if there appears to be a pattern of abuse that the moderators should be aware of, then please do flag it.

There are some actions that moderators can take, if we decide that a user's contributions are not welcome.  For example, we can send a stern warning to the user, impose sanctions such as temporary bans, or in extreme cases disable the account altogether.

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to flag every time you remove cursing.  You should only flag *if there's a problem that requires moderator attention*.  Individual cases of cursing does not warrant this, especially as it can be simply edited out if it's bad enough.

If you've been noticing it from a particular user, *and* they refuse to stop if it's indeed a serious matter (excessive cursing that's not at all constructive), *then* you can flag for moderator attention, and they'll deal with that user if necessary.